# Is it possible to store binary files inside an exe

Tags: c++, file

Is it possible to do this: (for educational purpose).

suppose I have a image file "image.jpg"
I want to create a program when it executes it should create this image. That means the data of the image is stored in the exe. Is this possible to do?

Something like this: link the image file from resource.rc then tell the compiler to get the data and store it (something like this `unsigned char data_buffer[]="binary data of the image"` then when the program is executed I can write this data to a file)

(I'm using C++ with mingw compiler)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If I were you, I'd take the approach writing a program that generates C++-friendly hexadecimal integer arrays from binary files, and I'd copy-paste its output into the source file.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Most executable's store an icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

1) Add it as a byte array in a source file. It is trivial to write an auxiliary program that reads the bytes from the files and writes the C source. E.g.:

#### data_jpg.c:

```
unsigned char data_jpg[] = {1,2,3... };
```

#### data_jpg.h:

```
extern char data_jpg[];
const size_t data_jpg_size = 1000;
```

2) Add it as a binary resource to the executable. You said "exe", did you? So you are likely on Windows. Window EXE files can have binary resources, that can be located using the resource API. See the `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `GlobalLock`, functions.

#### resource.rc

```
ID_DATA_JPG FILE "data.jpg"
```

3) Convert the binary file directly into a OBJ file and link it into the executable. In the old good days of turbo-c used to be a BINOBJ tool for that. And GNU tools can do it, AFAIk, but with MS tools, I really cannot tell.

Comment: I added `unsigned char data[]="ÿØÿà JFIF ......."` to image.h and tried to write the array data to a file. it gives many errors.

Comment: @LakshanPerera, you really have to convert your data to integers and store them like rodrigo did. Strings have to be escaped and their encoding depends on the encoding of the source file.

Comment: please explain the second option. after adding the line to resource how to get this data from the source

Comment: @LakshanPerera: Added the names of the API functions to load the resources. Note that some of these may seem as NO-OPS, but are there to guarantee compatibility with old/new versions of windows.

Answer (score 1):

With a PE file, you can add data(include bin data) to the PE file's tail as your resource. You just remember the PE file's size. But I'm not sure of that whether you need change the PE's checksum. And use VC++ Compiler to embed resources would be pretty much easy.